# Hyperref bug with a \def

Tags: hyperref

The following very MWE shows the issue, which disappears when the call to hyperref is commented:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\n{\textup{\tiny N}}
\def\t{\textup{\tiny T}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

${}_{\t}$
$_{\t}$
${}_{\t}$
$_\t$

\end{document}
```

However, it compiles fine when `hyperref` is called before the two `\def`.

Comment: `hyperref` or one of the packages it loads redefines `\t`. I suggest you take a different name for you macro, one letter names are always tightly contested and therefore dangerous. BTW: This is one of the reasons why it makes sense to (1) load all packages before you define custom commands and apply other (re-)definitions and (2) to use `\newcommand`. If you had `\usepackage{hyperref}\newcommand\t{\textup{\tiny T}}`, you would have gotten an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`, you'll clearly see the source of the problem:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \t already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

The `\t` command is defined in the LaTeX Internal Character Representation for the “tie accent” and `hyperref` assumes this is the meaning of `\t`. Since it has to do several patches for its working, you end up with `\t` being essentially redefined to its original meaning, which can be seen if you add `\show\t` after `\begin{document}`

```
> \t=macro:
->\PD1-cmd \t \PD1\t .
```

Without your redefinition and without `hyperref`, you'd get

```
> \t=macro:
->\OML-cmd \t \OML\t .
```

which is essentially the same (the encoding name may change when `\show` is used for technical reasons which are beyond the scope of this answer).

Moral: don't use `\def` if you don't know precisely what you're doing. And ***never*** redefine a command with `\renewcommand` if you don't know precisely about it.

Comment: Thanks. I should have guess but the error message disturbed me a bit.